# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, junit

**Сам тест**

```
@DirtiesContext
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/context.xml"})
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImplTest {User user = new User();

UserService userService = new UserServiceImpl();

@Before
public void setUp() {
    user.setLogin("dreven");
    user.setPassword("123456");
    user.setName("Dima");
    user.setLastname("Belousov");

}

@Test
public void testSave() {
    userService.save(user);
}

@Test
public void testFindByLogin() {
    userService.findByLogin("device");
}
}
```

**Классы которые исользует**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "login")
private String login;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "lastname")
private String lastname;

@Column(name = "avatar")
private String avatar;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Transient
private String confirmPassword;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
Set<Role> roles;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public String getAvatar() {
    return avatar;
}

public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
    this.avatar = avatar;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getConfirmPassword() {
    return confirmPassword;
}

public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
    this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
}

public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
}
```

**Этот класс тестю**

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
@Qualifier("userDao")
@Autowired
UserDao userDao;

@Qualifier("roleDao")
@Autowired
RoleDao roleDao;

@Autowired
BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Override
public void save(User user) {
    user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
    roles.add(roleDao.getOne(1L));
    user.setRoles(roles);
    userDao.saveAndFlush(user);


}

@Override
public User findByLogin(String login) {
    return userDao.findByLogin(login);
}
}
```

**UserDao**

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
User findByLogin(String login);
}
```

**RoleDao**

```
@Repository
public interface RoleDao extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {
}
```

**context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    ">

<context:annotation-config/>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.corporation.elanuimteam.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.corporation.elanuimteam.service"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.corporation.elanuimteam.validator"/>

<bean id="bCryptPasswordEncoder"
      class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>
<bean id="authenticationManager"      class="org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager"
      abstract="true"/>


 </beans>
```

**Ошибка**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:276)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:278)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 17 in XML document from class path resource [context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 72; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'jpa:repositories'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:253)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: не инициализируется бин bCryptPasswordEncoder

Comment: Что сделать нужно?